# Performance bonus everyone except me

Tags: performance, bonus

I worked for this company which went into administration. Most employees lost their jobs including me. A couple of departments were kept there and both were given increased wages and a performance and retention bonus that they will receive. This is basically a whole years salary when they eventually get let go.

I’m back working at the company as a temp 2 months after it let me go and have been here 2 1/2 months.

So it basically boils down to the fact that some people have been here 2 months longer than me and will be getting 20k as a bonus when they can leave about a month after me and I won’t get anything.

Is there anything I can do to get rewarded some bonus when I’ve finished?

Comment: "as a temp" You are working for a company that make profits by cutting employees costs. don't expect anything.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add some punctuation? The first paragraph is especially hard to understand...

Comment: If you have not received a bonus is there not a qualifying measure that you do not qualify for? have you asked about this

Comment: Were you paid as a temp?  If so you were rewarded for your work with a pay check.

Comment: Was the other people temp workers too? What got them qualified for a bonus?

Answer (score 13):

> Is there anything I can do to get rewarded some bonus when I’ve
>   finished?

You could ask for a bonus. You could work really hard. You could point out that your situation is unfair compared to the others.

And if you are in a position with leverage, you could threaten to leave immediately if you don't get the bonus.

Other than that, you should assume that you will get only what is in your contract and nothing more.

You were let go. They were retained.
And they were rewarded for sticking around. So it goes.

Comment: Yep, nothing to see here, move along....

Answer (score 3):

Your time to negotiate that was when they brought you back.  Now that you have been there for a while you have no leverage.

That said, you also have nothing holding you there.  I hope you are actively looking for other employment while doing this 'temp' work.  That is something your co-workers cannot do or they jeopardize their bonuses.  So in the end, if you play your cards right and have something found and ready to start before things wind all the way down, you are good to go, can give notice, and move on.  The others will need that bonus money to cover the time period they will be looking for the new employment.

Note: The others can look for employment, but most new employers are not going to want to wait for them to finish up and get their bonus before starting the new job.  So they are essential handcuffed, which is the origin of the phrase 'golden handcuffs'.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately unless the company is contractually obliged, payments of bonuses are solely at their discretion.

You may ask why you're apparently the only one who didn't get a bonus, but you can't expect that payment and most likely won't get it.

Are you certain it was even a bonus and not the remainder of your colleagues contract term or holiday pay?